# Is it real connect subtitles when streaming video (HLS, M3U8)

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8, subtitle

I am trying to create a stream in which the tracks from the convertible  file (in my case .mkv to .m3u8) will be played through m3u8. At the moment, it turns out to switch between multiple resolutions, and even select the audio track, but does not see the subtitles at all.

Video works, audio tracks are switched, but no subtitles are visible at all

ffprobe source file:
https://paste2.org/czUePDPj

Next, perform coding and splitting into tracks:

```
ffmpeg -i '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/Rick.mkv' \
-map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset:v superfast -strict -2 -s 426x240   -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -segment_list rick240p -hls_segment_filename '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/Rick240p_%d.ts'      '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/Rick240p.m3u8' \
-map 0:a:0 -c:a aac                             -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -segment_list rick_ru -hls_segment_filename '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/RickTrack_ru_%d.aac'        '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/RickTrack_ru.m3u8' \
-map 0:a:1 -c:a aac                             -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -segment_list rick_en -hls_segment_filename '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/RickTrack_en_%d.aac'        '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/RickTrack_en.m3u8' \
-map 0:s:0 suben.vtt                          -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -segment_list en -hls_segment_filename '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/sub_en_%d.vtt'  '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/sub_en.m3u8' \
-map 0:s:1 subru.vtt                          -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -segment_list ru -hls_segment_filename '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/sub_ru_%d.vtt'  '/home/mishkapetran/Загрузки/test/sub_ru.m3u8'
```

Then in the same folder I create the m3u8 master:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="Russian",LANGUAGE="ru",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="RickTrack_ru.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",NAME="English",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=NO,URI="RickTrack_en.m3u8"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Russian",DEFAULT=YES,FORCED=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="ru",URI="sub_ru.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=NO,FORCED=NO,AUTOSELECT=YES,LANGUAGE="en",URI="sub_en.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=928000,CODECS="avc1.42c00d,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=480x270,AUDIO="audio",SUBTITLES="subs"
Rick240p.m3u8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week of searching, everything was decided quite simply:
Subtitles work correctly with the .vtt extension, but you need to specify application / octet-stream in type.
For me it works like this:

```
<video id="stream_video_tag" width="800" height="600" controls>
<source src="index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
<track src="sub_en.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" kind="subtitles" 
type="application/octet-stream">
<track src="sub_ru.vtt" srclang="ru" label="Russian" kind="subtitles" 
type="application/octet-stream">
</video>
```